# Can a pole be ignorned in a numerical integration? If not, can it be removed?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I'm evaluating this function:
$$
G(z):=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2d\omega}\omega\int_0^\infty dP\cos(Pz)\sigma(\omega,P)\\
G(z)=\int_0^\infty dP\int_{-P^2}^\infty ds\frac{\cos(Pz)}{s+P^2}\sigma(s,P)\\
G(z)=\int_0^\infty ds\int_{Re(\sqrt{-s})}^\infty dP\frac{\cos(Pz)}{s+P^2}\sigma(s,P)\\
s:=\omega^2-P^2
$$
$\sigma(\omega,P)$ is even in $P$ and odd in $\omega$ and must have a non-zero derivative with respect to $\omega$ at $\omega=0$. It must be constant in $P$ for sufficiently large $P$ and positive $s$, or sufficiently large $P$ and $\omega>P$. I evaluate the second and third versions because they reduce the apparent $P$-dependence of $\sigma$ when I have it tabulated, increasing the accuracy of the result. I appear to have a Dirac delta function when I evaluate the P integral and inverse Fourier transform. I've narrowed it down to the linear $\omega$ term of the Taylor series of $\sigma$.

The following plot is what happens when I evaluate the following $\sigma$ which broadly has the properties I'm interested in while being simpler to evaluate than the tabulated $\sigma$:
$$
\sigma(s,P):=\frac{A\Gamma(s,P)M\sqrt{\frac{s+P^2}{M^2+P^2}}}{\pi((s-M^2)^2+\Gamma^2(s,P)M^2\frac{s+P^2}{M^2+P^2}}\\
\Gamma(s,P):=\Gamma_0\exp(5+\frac12(\sqrt{s+P^2}-\sqrt{M^2+P^2}-10\sqrt{1+(\sqrt{M^2+P^2}-\sqrt{s+P^2})^2}))\\
A:=.3\ \ M:=3.04\ \ \Gamma:=.032
$$
The horizontal axis is $s$. The vertical axis is the $s$-integrand, that is, the $P$-integral of the third $G(z)$ has been evaluated, for $z$=6.25. That massive spike at $s$=0 may or may not be there. It is acting like a Dirac delta; the next sample points to the left or right are $s=\pm10^{-12}$. Everything else well outside this range is very smooth.

[image: Plot of s-integrand, the result of evaluating the p-integral for selected s and z=6.25, zoomed way in indicating a Dirac delta function]

The question that I have is, is there actually a Dirac delta there and not numerical rubbish? And if it is there, what should I do about it? That is, how do I determine the strength of the Dirac delta function? I'm concerned there's actually a Dirac delta there as the next integral up needs to know about Dirac delta functions but not zero width numerical anomalies. As $\sigma$ is linear at $\omega=0$ that would imply that $\sigma(\omega,P)/\omega$ is a finite value and it might have a Dirac delta associated with it that needs to be properly considered.

Edit: I've been working on the problem some more and have figured out what is wrong. $\sigma$ is even in P. At $s$=0, the kernel ($\frac{\cos(Pz)}{s+P^2}$) is $1/0^2$. That means $\sigma$ must go to zero as $P^2$. Based on its properties listed above, you would think this is case. It is not and instead has a cusp like $|P|$ which is insufficient to the needs of the function. $\sigma$ is quadratic for $s\neq0$ at $P=0$ as you would expect. So it is just this one point. So, the apparent Dirac delta isn't supposed to be there in physical cases, but for the given $\sigma$ it is correct. But that changes the questions: 1) Can this be ignored while evaluating this numerically? 2) If not, is there a way to make $\sigma$ come to zero as $P^2$ and not $|P|$? I suspect that the $|P|$ comes from looking at $\omega^2=P^2$.

Comment: There are many limit representations of the Dirac delta function (e.g. see formulas 34-41 at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html). Your function is unlikely to be a representation of the Dirac delta function unless you can express it as a limit representation. One characteristic of the Dirac delta function is $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\,dx=1$, but even if you had a limit representation that didn't integrate to $1$ you might be able to normalize it my multiplying it by a constant.

Comment: @StevenClark, I found the cause. I need to figure out the resolution now.